# how to find / filter crashes on new Android studio logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, fatal-error

How to filter the FATAL EXCEPTION on the new Android Studio Dolphin logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the new logcat on Android studio Dolphin

Here is the filter query for filtering out the crashes.

```
package:mine tag:AndroidRuntime level:ERROR  FATAL EXCEPTION
```

Happy Coding :)